# How to use hasNext() from the Scanner class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, eof

**Input Format**

Read some unknown n lines of input from `stdin(System.in)` until you reach EOF; each line of input contains a non-empty String.

**Output Format**

For each line, print the line number, followed by a single space, and then the line content received as input:

**Sample Output**

```
Hello world
I am a file
Read me until end-of-file.
```

Here is my solution. The problem being I am not able to proceed till EOF.
But the output is just:

```
Hello world
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check(1);  // call check method
    }

    static void check(int count) {          
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(s.hasNext() == true) {
            String ns = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
            count++;
            check(count);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `if(s.hasNext()==true){` evaluates only once. Use `while`.

Comment: why are you using recursion in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code does not work because you create a new `Scanner` object in every recursive call.
You should not use recursion for this anyways, do it iteratively instead.

**Iterative version**

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 1;

        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String ns = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Recursive version**

```
public class Solution {

    private Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = new Scanner(System.in); // initialize only once
        check(1);
    }

    public static void check(int count) {
        if(s.hasNext()) {
            String ns = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
            check(count + 1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (s.hasNext() == true) {
    String ns = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
    count++;
    System.out.print(count);
    check(count);
}
```

to:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String ns = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
    count++;
    System.out.print(count);
    check(count);
}
```

`while` loops continues until the data exists, where as `if` checks for only once.

Comment: Yes, thanks but I am calling the check function recursively for incremented values.

Answer (score 1):

If using recursion is a requirement, you can use a helper function:

```
static void check(int count) {          
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    check(count, s);
} 

static void check(int count, Scanner scanner) {
    if(!scanner.hasNext()) {
        return;
    }
    String ns = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
    check(++count, scanner);
}
```

Notice how `new Scanner(System.in)` is only called once.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` is kind of a `BufferedReader` (I'm not telling about inheritance or something. I'm telling they both have buffers. `Scanner` has just a small one). So after you enter text in the Console, those are `read()` from `System.in` and stored in the buffer inside the `Scanner`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {          
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    s1.hasNext();
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Read line:: " + s2.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Use the following input to the `Scanner`:

> line 1
>   line 2
>   line 3
>   line 4

You will get the output:

> Read line:: e 1
>   Read line:: line 2
>   Read line:: line 3
>   Read line:: line 4

I think you might know the reason to this output. Some characters of the first line are in the `Scanner s1`. Therefore **don't** create 2 `Scanner`s to take input from same `Stream`.

You can change your code as follows to get required output.

```
private static Scanner s;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    check(1);  // call check method
}

static void check(int count) {
    if (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String ns = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(count + " " + ns);
        count++;
        check(count);
    }
}
```

You can use `s.hasNextLine()` instead of `s.hasNext()` as you are reading line by line.

No need to use `s.hasNextLine()==true` as that statement will be `true` if and only if `s.hasNextLine()` is `true`.

You can give `EOF` character to the console using `Ctrl+Z` in Windows system and `Ctrl+D` in Unix. As I know, you can't send `EOF` character using the output window of NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> eol = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=1;
    while(in.hasNext()){

        eol.add(in.nextLine());
    }

    for (String i:eol){

        System.out.println(t+" "+i);
        t++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 1;
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(count++ + " " + scan.nextLine());            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error free program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 1;
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(count + " " + s);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 1;
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(i + " " + scanner.nextLine());
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use while instead of if,but recursive version is better.Here is iterative version:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            int i=0;

          while(sc.hasNext()==true)
            {
                i=i+1;
                 String s=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(i+" "+s);

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Scanner.hasNext()` basically helps you to read the input. This method returns true if this Scanner has another token of any type in its input. Returns false otherwise.
 Check below code snippet,

```
 while(sc.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(i + " " + sc.nextLine());
      i++;
 }
```

You can find complete code at below link,

https://github.com/hetalrachh/HackerRank/blob/master/Practice/Java/Introduction/EndOfFile.java

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this to get desired result:

public class EOF {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i =1;scan.hasNext();i++) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(i + " " + line);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=1; scan.hasNext() ; 
    System.out.println(i++ +" "+scan.nextLine()));
        
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches -

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> inputLines = new ArrayList();

    int i=1;
    while(inputScanner.hasNext()) {
        inputLines.add(i+" "+inputScanner.nextLine());
        i++;
    }

    inputLines.stream().forEach(k->System.out.println(k));
}
```